# How do I list all connected clients in flask_socketio?

Tags: websocket, flask-socketio, python-socketio

Is there any way to list every sid connected to a flask_socketio server?  Trawling through the API documentation, every function to list sessions requires a room, and every function to list rooms requires a sid in that room.

Comment: There is no way to list connected clients. Your application can keep track of this list in a database by updating the list in connect and disconnect handlers.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg How would this work when dealing with multiple workers? e.g. when a server instance crashes (and can thus not trigger the disconnect events) it is not clear which clients disconnected and which ones remain connected to different workers. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @FrankMartin you can add a timestamp to your database that records the last time the client communicated with the server, and purge any entries that are older than some threshold.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg thank you, the most convenient way of doing this would be through the ping from the `engineio` (https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-engineio/blob/de4459422e488775d9e7d757f5682d0a9d0114e2/src/engineio/server.py#L749). However this is not an socketio event. Any suggestions on this? Else we would be needing to add a ping layer at the socketio level.. which would be a bit of a waste of traffic

Comment: @FrankMartin I don't have any other suggestions, with the current code the ping/pong mechanism is internal and not intended to be used across multiple servers.